# Get dynamic content Python from a HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a bot with Python for a **typing website**. The problem is that I can't get the text of an HTML tag.

When I get the website's source (after loading the JS), the element containing the text I want stills not appearing, although I can find it in the **Inspect Element** window of Chrome.
Also, I think the element is inside some `<iframe>`, and the tag is `<text>`.

Comment: " think the element is inside some <iframe>" - don't guess; confirm using DevTools. See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=switch#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it and https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=switch#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to

Comment: If it's inside the iframe, can I retrieve the text though?

Comment: Sure. But you need to switch to the iframe first. The links I gave show how

Comment: The element is inside an iframe, thanks for your advice

Comment: If you have further problems, just post the code you have and the full traceback if any.

Comment: I was able to fix the code thanks to you. It should be all t he help I need